# JS works until I bring it into a foundation Framework

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am working on a project where I want to make it look as if a shutter of a camera is opening and closing... I was able to get this to work in a regular html/css/js file structure however when I trie to bring/ incorporate it into Foundations Responsive Frameworks I was not able to get it to work.  There are no errors in the console and checked to make sure everything is linked correctly. ... I have attached both folders in the link, the working folder that is not in a framework and the broken folder that I am trying to use foundations framework..
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4EHdofHefLHZjZpczBybE1xWGs&usp=sharing

Thank you in advance for any feedback/help.
-Jake

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot fix it.
Fortunately, I did figure out the problem.

The jquery.shutter.css is not loading properly. [Here is my attempt at your project in React](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Byq8GZtYpNkheGtNbzJpR3A1cWc&usp=sharing).

When I take your working example and delete the jquery.shutter.css file, I get the exact same result as the React version which has no error message. I gave it a good try and cannot fix it without more time. I hope knowing the problem helps you.

Note: Unfortunately Google will not let me upload a JSON file so you will have to change package.txt to package.json and install using Node